# NSTextView or NSTextField automatically resize bounds / frame?

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstableview, nstextfield, nstextview

I'm trying to use either an NSTextView or NSTextField which displays text that I am adding via `textField.stringValue = [dictionary objectForKey:@"info"];`

The problem is I need the bounds / frame of the text area to vertically re-size to show all of the text. The text varies from a couple of words (1 line) to a paragraph or two.

When I try `[textField sizeToFit];`

It re-sizes the whole thing down to a single line which is absurdly too long (and goes off view). I need it to auto re-size its width according to the current window width and based off of that re-size its height to keep showing all the text.

Any ideas on what to try or direction? This is for OSX no iOS.

*(This TextField or TextView is going in a **View Based** - NSTableView. So I am eventually trying to get my tables to dynamically re-size their row height based on that text box.)*

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do something similar to this on my current project.  The trick is to use the `sizeWithFont` method on `NSString`. This will return a `CGSize` which you can then use to build a correctly sized frame to fit your text.

```
-(void) setCaption: (NSString*) text size:(CGSize) maxSize
{
    [self.label setText:text];
    UIFont* font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize: [UIFont systemFontSize]]
    [[self label] setFont:font];

    CGSize size=[text sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:maxSize];  
    label.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
}
```

If you don't have access to the view, then you could roll this up into a Class helper method.

Comment: That seems like it could do the trick. I'll check it out in just a bit!

Comment: do you happen do know what the equivalent of `CGSize size=[text sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:maxSize];` for OSX would be? Something along the lines of `CGSize size = [text sizeWithAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjetc:font forKey:NSFonrAttributeName]];`?

Comment: Yes, I believe sizeWithAttributes is what you want.

Comment: Did you solve this problem?  If you manually control the frame size - what event is triggering this to happen?

Comment: Is there still a way to do this in Swift? I looked up the documentation and "sizeWithFont" is no longer supported in Obj C or Swift.